# Discover port of other service in Kubernetes, without using the FOO_SERVICE_PORT env variable

Tags: kubernetes, service-discovery, azure-aks

According to the Kubernetes documentation, [each container gets a set of environment variables that lets it access other services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#services)

> For example, if a Service named foo exists, all containers will get the following variables in their initial environment:
>
> ```
> FOO_SERVICE_HOST=<the host the Service is running on>
> FOO_SERVICE_PORT=<the port the Service is running on>
> ```

However, it seems that in my cluster I'm not getting the expected values in those variables:

```
tlycken@local: k exec -ti <my-pod> ash
/app # echo $SEARCH_HOST

/app # echo $SEARCH_PORT
tcp://10.0.110.126:80
```

I would rather have expected to see something like

```
tlycken@local: k exec -ti <my-pod> ash
/app # echo $SEARCH_HOST
10.0.110.126
/app # echo $SEARCH_PORT
80
```

I know that the docs also say

> If you are writing code that talks to a Service, don’t use these environment variables; use the DNS name of the Service instead.

but that only gives me the host name, not the port, of the service. Therefore, I wanted to set `SEARCH_HOST` to `search` in my deployment template and rely on `SEARCH_PORT` to get the port, but when I put the service url together from the existing environment variables, it becomes `http://search:tcp://10.0.110.126:80` which obviously does not work.

If I can't rely on the `FOO_SERVICE_PORT` variable to give me the port number, what should I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a part from `kubernetes` documentation posted in the question:

> For example, if a Service named foo exists, all containers will get
>   the following variables in their initial environment:
>
> ```
> FOO_SERVICE_HOST=<the host the Service is running on>
> FOO_SERVICE_PORT=<the port the Service is running on>
> ```

The variable name is `<your_service_name>_SERVICE_PORT`, so if your server has name `SEARCH`, you are able to find it `host` and `port` values using `SEARCH_SERVICE_HOST` and `SEARCH_SERVICE_PORT` environment variables:

```
echo $SEARCH_SERVICE_HOST

echo $SEARCH_SERVICE_PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I can't rely on the FOO_SERVICE_PORT variable to give me the port number, what should I do instead?

I think the best way is to use `SRV` records for resolving information about service because a DNS of the cluster is providing that Service Discovery feature.

Here is an official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#srv-records) about it, but in few words, the record looks like that:

`<my-port-name>.<my-port-protocol>.<my-svc>.<my-namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

So, for your service it will be like:

`foo-port.tcp.foo.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`, where `my-namespace` is a namespace of `foo` service.

Address of your service can be obtained  from `foo.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local` record.

Comment: You can use some library for work with DNS records, but you can also just call something like `dig +short foo-port.tcp.foo.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local SRV|awk '{print $3}'`.